# about argument to member function

Tags: c++

Will adding an argument to member function  gonna change the behavior of the function?

Need help about this concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior won't change if you only add an argument to the prototype of the function.

However you will have to change all the call to this function since the prototype changed, this isn't the same function anymore.

And sincerely, I don't see the point of adding an argument if you don't modify the code afterward.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to give us more information. Like an example. But say you add a new argument (and provide a default), and now argument will be "constructed" and destructed everywhere the member function was called. So it's possible that that in itself has side-effects (e.g. print to console on creationg and destruction).